# How do I insert Webpack-generated code into a server-side node.js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have a web-application written in Typescript. No frameworks because they don't suit my tasks. The app is compiled with Webpack. So far it works fine. Then I wanted to implement server-side rendering of some parts of the app. I want some parts of my code and my html-pages along with images and styles be served by a node.js script.

So. I am trying to configure Webpack to make me a js-file that I could then `require` into my another `ssr.js` node.js server script.
But I don't know how to do it. The resulting script is wrapped into something and it stumbles upon `window` not being defined and not being equal to `global` namespace.

How do I approach the task? Is Webpack in general suitable for compiling server-side scripts? If not then how else do I go about server-side rendering?

My `.ts` file are process with the `ts-loader`:

```
{
   test: /\.ts$/,
   use: 'ts-loader',
},
```

Update:
I added `target: 'node'` as proposed in another question but it isn't enough in general. The errors with `window` are gone but now I can't connect what I `export` with what I `require`;

My file looks  like this:

```
export function someFunc(x) {
    // Some code
}
```

I expect that I can do

```
const something = require('somefile');
```

and the fetch my `someFunc` from within `sonething`. But this does not work. In place of `something` I get a strange object that looks like this:

```
{ ids: [ 0 ],
  modules: 
   [ [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function] ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no window object present webpack nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704936/no-window-object-present-webpack-nodejs)

Comment: Why would you use webpack to bundle the scripts for the server side? Just directly require the individual modules (compile with Typescript as necessary).

Comment: You can definitely use webpack on the server side, though, as @Bergi mentions, it isn't always necessary. Perhaps the [target](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) option can help you. For server-side you should set it to 'node'.

Comment: If I don't use Webpack then I will have to use two compilation systems instead of one. I have to somehow compile sass and typescript. And then there are html-files and images that have to be properly connected to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had two problems. One was already answered, I had to set Webpack's `target` to `node`.
Now I found what was the second issue. It was `CommonsChunkPlugin`. This plugin is not compatible with `taget: 'node'`. I had to remove it for server side.